# Please identify hard hollow structure found on beach

Tags: marine-biology

This washed up on the shore in NJ last week. It looks like a molar but I cannot find anything similar [image]

1.75” across about 1/2 high. It has a weird indent too[image]

Comment: Most likely a shell. We would need some sort of scale for size and photos of other surfaces for full ID.

Comment: StackExchange works differently from other sites: the answer box is for answers *only*, it's not a forum with a string of posts replying to an original. If you need your accounts merged you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page or https://biology.stackexchange.com/contact If you have new content to add use the [edit] feature.

Comment: Is it actually bone? all kinds of weathered junk washes up on NJ beaches

Comment: IT could be an old ceramic tube like a piece of a clay bottle, a weight for a net from an indian.

Comment: The most defining thing is the holes on one side, it has a hole in the top too. Use reddit or FB fossil ID or what's this fossil or fossil forums they specialize in weird beach finds.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/fossilid/